# View all gaps in randomly-spaced timestamps (primary key) within a mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I have a few mysql databases that I need to find gaps in data for. My primary key is a timestamp, specifically "time since epoch".

So my table looks like:

```
timestamp,val1,val2,
1498774516,..,..
1498774634,..,..
1498774848,..,..
```

The timestamp is also the primary key. Note that the timestamps have random-sized intervals between them; it's not a simple case of iterating a counter by a constant amount like other answers I've seen.

I would like to know a great mysql command to find when there's  a gap between two timestamps. Specifically, I'd like to know when two sequential timestamps have a difference greater than 900 seconds, and get some kind of index/timestamp for this window.

I'm wondering if there's a native mySQL command to do this, or whether I should just take all of the first column values for a database and analyze them that way. If it's the latter... how can I just get all of the first column values for a mysql database? Won't this suck when I have like 1TB of data in my database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the pairs of adjacent timestamps that are more than 900 seconds different with a query like this:

(EDITED)

```
select
    timestamp1,
    timestamp2
from (
    select 
        t1.timestamp as timestamp1,
        min(t2.timestamp) as timestamp2
    from
        thetable as t1,
        thetable as t2
    where
        t2.timestamp > t1.timestamp
    group by
        t1.timestamp
    ) as times
where
    timestamp2 > timestamp1 + 900;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference by storing previous value in temporary variable, e,g.:

```
SELECT timestamp, (timestamp - @previous) AS difference, @previous := timestamp
FROM test_time, (SELECT @previous := 0) a
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Once done, you can wrap this query into another `SELECT` and get the rows with difference more than 900, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT timestamp, (timestamp - @previous) AS difference, @previous := 
  timestamp
  FROM test_time, (SELECT @previous := 0) a
  ORDER BY timestamp
) a
WHERE a.timestamp <> a.difference AND a.difference > 900;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think, because my primary key is a randomly-spaced timestamp, this question was a bit harder than it first implied. A lot of similar questions' answers don't apply.

Comment: This will give you the timestamps that have gaps between them, and you can then write a logic in your service layer or middleware to calculate index/timestamp for that window?

Comment: thanks... maybe a dumb question... but would you be able to edit your answer to indicate where I should select the table/database I'll be using? i'm testing this now and running into a parse error, I think because i'm not specifying the table. like where would it put "FROM database.tableName"

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can use <db_name>.<table_name> in `FROM` clause or just <table_name> if you have already executed `use dbname;` command.